# ASM Extended on RISCV GCC Immediate issue

Tags: assembly, gcc, riscv

I'm trying to pass an immediate value (12bit size) containing the address of a CSR register into the csr instruction of riscv. Do you have any idea?

```
int volatile stimulus[] = {0xabbaabba, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xAAAAAAAA};

void  test_csr0(){
    int imm1 = stimulus[0];
    int imm2 = stimulus[1];

    int test = 0x300;
    asm volatile (
            "lw t1, %[imm1];"
            "lw t4, %[imm2];"
            "csrrc x0,  %[imm3],t2;"
            :
            :[imm1] "m" (imm1), [imm2] "m" (imm2),[imm3] "I" (test) ); //
```

the error is the following:

```
make all
CC  test.c
In file included from test.c:12:0: 
csr_test/csr_test0.c: In function 'test_csr0':

csr_test/csr_test0.c:19:9: warning: asm operand 2 probably doesn't match constraints

   asm volatile (
   ^~~

csr_test/csr_test0.c:19:9: error: impossible constraint in 'asm'
```

Is there a way to use an array of const int instead of the normal test variable? What I mean is the following:

```
void  test_csr0() {
    unsigned stimulus[] = {0xabbaabba, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xAAAAAAAA};
    int imm1 = stimulus[0];
    int imm2 = stimulus[1];
    const int test[] = {0x300, 0x25c, 0xc70, 0x7c0};
    for (int i; i<4;i++){
        asm volatile (
            "lw t1, %[imm1];"
            "lw t4, %[imm2];"
            "csrrc x0,  %[imm3],t2;"
            :
            :[imm1] "m" (imm1), [imm2] "m" (imm2),[imm3] "I" (test[i]) ); 
    }
}
```

I need to pass all the addresses to this function. Than you again!

Comment: Did you compile with optimization disabled?  That won't do constant-propagation so `test` won't be a known compile-time constant because you didn't declare it `const int`.

Comment: Also, reading `stimulus[0];` before `int stimulus[]` is declared looks like a bug, or just very bad design (if you're reading a global-scope `stimulus[]` that is is later shadowed by the local var of the same name)

Comment: Yup, compiles with `-O1`, after adding a missing `}` and fixing order of declaration of locals. https://godbolt.org/z/PGTYq5.  Using `const int` works at `-O0` if you compile as C++, but not as C :/  https://godbolt.org/z/cKzMx7

Comment: Thank you Peter, I fixed the issue declaring the variable as constant. Thank you a lot for you help!

Comment: With optimization enabled, GCC should be able to fully unroll the loop so each `test[i]` is a compile-time constant after all.  Of course writing your source this way means you *can't* compile without optimization anymore.  So you might want an `__attribute__` to set optimization level for that one function to `"O3"`.  I forget the exact syntax.

Comment: Of course it's really silly to `lw` the same two values every time, so you should really just take them in registers and let the compiler load them once.  (Like you should have even for the non-looping version.)

Comment: There is also `#pragma GCC unroll <n>` to enforce unrolling of `n` loops but I was not able to successfully use either to get inline assembly to accept variables in place of immediate values (in my case the variable was function-local not a parameter).